# Error: You attempted to overwrite the built-in helper "array". Where is this coming from?

Tags: ember.js

How do I track down where this error is coming from? I searched my own codebase, and could not find anywhere that I was using the `{{array}}` helper. It happens during an acceptance test.

> You attempted to overwrite the built-in helper "array" which is not allowed. Please rename the helper.

I am attempting to update some of my Ember dependencies, which surfaced this problem.

Answer (score 10):

In the end, I did `ember build` and searched the contents of `dist` for `helpers/array`. This revealed an import from [`ember-composable-helpers`](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers/tree/v2.4.0):

```
;define("dummy/helpers/array", ["exports", "ember-composable-helpers/helpers/array"], function (_exports, _array) {
```

I was using a 2.x version of ember-composable-helpers. In version 3.0, the array helper was removed from the addon, since it became a standard helper provided by Ember itself.

Updating my ember-composable-helpers version to 3.x solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the procedure! following it allowed me to know the error (though the overwrite was from my own code :D)